# Locate command is returning too many results

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, duplicate, duplicate-files

I made the mistake of copying the same files to different partitions with good intentions of pruning (deleting) them from the source or target(s) later. Now when I try to locate them I get too many results from `locate` command:

```
rick@alien:~$ locate "display-auto-brightness"
/etc/cron.d/display-auto-brightness
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness conky.png
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness systray.png
/home/rick/Pictures/display-auto-brightness-config 1.png
/home/rick/Pictures/ps display-auto-brightness.png
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/etc/cron.d/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/lib/systemd/system-sleep/display-auto-brightness
/mnt/e/usr/local/bin/display-auto-brightness
/usr/local/bin/display-auto-brightness
```

The `locate` command is automatically placing the `*` wild card after the search string and returning extra undesired results. The `.png` files should not be returned.

Why is `locate` returning too many results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `locate` command is automatically placing the * wild card after the search string and returning extra undesired results.

That is the default behaviour of `locate`. See [`man locate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mlocate.1.html):

```
If any PATTERN contains no globbing characters, locate  behaves  as  if
the pattern were *PATTERN*.
```

To match only against the filename, explicitly set a glob in the path component:

```
locate '*/display-auto-brightness'
```

Or use a regex and the `--basename` option for matching an exact filename:

```
locate --basename --regex '^display-auto-brightness$'
```

Or, given the results you have shown, you could get away with just asking for paths that contain `display-auto-brightness` at the end:

```
locate --regex 'display-auto-brightness$'
```

I'll leave it you to use this in a script looping over each filename in a directory.

Comment: If acceptable to you I propose changing the question to "How to prevent locate from finding too many files" using `locate 'display-auto-brightness'` example. Then I would accept your answer as is. I'll post a new self-answered question later after writing script that finds clones.

Comment: Sure, but you can just post and accept your answer to this question too

Comment: I want you to get credit for `locate --regex 'display-auto-brightness$'` I also think that micro-component of the project will benefit other users where as the bigger three way sync of files only interests a few people.